# Limit of a function: restriction value of delta

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

This is an exercise question from Calculus: Single Variable 10th edition, Saas Hille Etgen, there is one thing I don't really understand here.

So by observing the graph, I understand that $\epsilon_1$ would definitely work, since every value within ($c-\delta$, $c+\delta$) is mapped for the chosen $\epsilon$, but I am not sure, I think in this exercises, I think $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ should all work since still that every value within ($c-\delta$, $c+\delta$) can be mapped.

My solution key tells me only $\epsilon_1$ work, I don't really understand why though in this case, can someone explain a little bit to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, the graph shows the output $y$ values are in $(L-\epsilon_2,L+\epsilon_1)$. Since $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2<\epsilon_3$, the farthest we can allow $y$ to vary is $\epsilon_1$.